# Is my Hotmail compromised as many emails have been sent automatically?

Tags: email, account-security

There were hundreds of emails sent from my Hotmail account between 30 Aug to 1 Sept to many Hotmail and Outlook addresses with `sECURED.shtml` attachment of 764KB. Some emails were not delivered and deleted from my inbox automatically. How can I track who did this or which program/app is doing this? Is my email compromised? Also what measures shall I take to secure my email account?

Comment: You need to work with Hotmail support.

Comment: Do you use programs/apps to access your Hotmail?

Comment: Is it possible to see all authorized devices on your Microsoft account?

Answer (score 1):

If you did not send the emails, then, yes, your account is clearly compromised.

Your Hotmail account should have a log of who logged in, which you can check.

The advice on securing online accounts are pretty standard over the past few years:

- reset your password to a strong, unguessable password
- enable two-factor authentication/multi-factor authentication

You need to work with Hotmail support to help through the rest of it and conduct an investigation.

Answer (score 0):

*How can I track who did this or which program/app is doing this? Is my email compromised?*

You can access your account history through https://account.live.com/Activity
This is the link I obtained from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/check-the-recent-sign-in-activity-for-your-microsoft-account-5b3cfb8e-70b3-2bd6-9a56-a50177863357

*Also what measures shall I take to secure my email account?*

To really be secure you need to know what happened first, it is no good only resetting your password if you have a keylogger installed for example. If you suspect you may have any malware, it is best to do a clean install in addition to resetting any passwords. However this can be tricky if you have multiple devices, so you need to also think did you access your account from a mobile device? could it have been on an unsecured network? You should run virus scans as it might detect which device has been compromised.

If it were me I would first reset the password, factory reset or format any devices with that email account and then reset the password a second time.

I would also ensure not to open any of those emails, especially the attachment.

Comment: You've jumped straight to malware but there is no indication of an infection. The far more likely scenario is that the account was remotely compromised. And even if you have a keylogger, resetting the password kicks off the remote person, and by adding MFA, if doesn't matter if you have a keylogger. So, this advice is overkill for the details provided. There is no reason to reset and reinstall every device that may have accessed an online service until there is evidence that the compromise is on a device.

Comment: @schroeder See where I wrote "If you suspect you may have any malware, it is best to do a clean install in addition to resetting any passwords." key word here is "If".

Comment: @schroeder also why do you think the far more likely scenario is that the account was remotely compromised. What from the OP did you base that on?

Comment: "If it were me I would first reset the password, factory reset or format any devices with that email account and then reset the password a second time." -- the "if" there is not based on confirmation of malware ...

Comment: Likelihood is based on 20 years of experience and threat intel and attack statistics over the past 5 years. It is *generally* more likely that it was a remote compromise of the account. So much more likely, that one should assume remote compromise until local device compromise becomes a viable hypothesis.

Comment: @schroeder I also asked him if he accessed his account from an unsecured network, the "if it were me" is because I am always on the cautious side. besides, there is nothing to suggest it was was remotely compromised from that OP either.

Comment: 80% of your answer is focused entirely on malware response. That's too much focus to give when there are other actual issues at play.

Comment: @schroeder I would be intrigued to see your data that "It is generally more likely that it was a remote compromise of the account". I thought phishing was still the most common attack vendor.

Comment: @schroeder also I think it is important to point out, it is a bit strange to say remote compromise is more likely than malware, because malware can be the reason for remote compromise. It is like saying vehicles are more common than cars.

Answer (score -1):

Were the e-mails actually sent from your account, or was your e-mail address just used as the sender address of this malware wave?

Both options are possible.

- In the first case you need to secure your account as explained before, of course. You also need to find out if

  - your PC is also compromised (and the mails were sent from your PC),
  - the password was somehow stolen, but the mail was sent from external IP addresses through your account,
  - or you may have inadvertantly given your account credentials to a bad actor by falling for a phishing attack (something like "we need to check your account, please log in here...").
- In the second case there is little you can do as your account wasn't actually involved in sending the bad mails.

So the first thing you should do (perhaps with help from some mail expert) is to analyze the bounces to see where the e-mails originated and which of these cases apply. Doing a thorough malware check on your PC isn't a bad idea in any case if you don't already do that regularly.

Comment: From the details provided, it appears that they are seeing these emails within their account. So, this isn't a spoofed address situation. Hotmail is web-based, so I'm not sure how the "PC" could have sent the emails. Analysis of headers will only show Hotmail, not the connecting party. The account connection logs will provide more relevant info than the email headers.

Comment: Yup that's possibly right, I have no experience with Hotmail whatsoever, only client based mail (POP/IMAP/SMTP). Account connection logs might indeed be the right place to look first.